# git hash-object vs shasum doesn't match when the content starts with a number

Tags: git, hash, sha1

I am trying to work on a custom solution to connect to a git API, and when I do a shasum on content that starts with letters, the results match:

```
$ echo -e -n "blob 4\0test" | shasum
30d74d258442c7c65512eafab474568dd706c430 *-

$ echo -e -n "test" | git hash-object --stdin
30d74d258442c7c65512eafab474568dd706c430
```

It doesn't match when the content starts with a number though:

```
$ echo -e -n "blob 5\0test" | shasum
315a7861230f24fade469e87c0c548f0cc4bc8c8 *-

$ echo -e -n "0test" | git hash-object --stdin
475a3cf5e5dadf80fe51cc8748c9bfdabae29f07
```

I'm stumped as to why it's giving different results, anybody know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `echo -e`, you're providing an octal escape when you write `\0`.  Adding additional digits after that causes them to be interpreted as octal digits in the octal escape.

Since POSIX doesn't define `echo -e` and it isn't portable, it's better to use `printf`, since you know that the octal escape will be interpreted consistently and can contain at most three digits:

```
$ printf "blob 5\0000test" | shasum
475a3cf5e5dadf80fe51cc8748c9bfdabae29f07  -
$ printf "0test" | git hash-object --stdin
475a3cf5e5dadf80fe51cc8748c9bfdabae29f07
```

In the first invocation, the `\0000` is the octal escape `\000` (a NUL byte) plus the character `0` (decimal 48).